# How to automatically refresh the HTTP cache？

Tags: http, caching

I have an **asp.net** web page generated by server **(IIS 8.5)**, it displays some graphs based on data stored in the back-end. I manually updated the database (bulk insert some data), and refresh the browser, but the page does not show the new data.

I think it a cache problem, since when I press `ctrl + F5`, the new data appears. So how should I solve this problem? Do something in the web server?

Answer (score 0):

You can control browser caching via the `Expires`, `Cache-Control`, `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers.

Take a look at these [two](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching) Google Developers [pages](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching).

If you want to disable caching at any cost, include a unique tag in your image URLs that changes every time the image content changes, for example:

```
http://example.test/path/to/image/graph1.png?version=2014-3-19
```

With `version` changing every time you update the image. Since it is a new URL it is guaranteed not to be cached. Be careful with this technique though, since using this technique when it's not really needed can lead to long loading times (since well, you disabled caching of the images).

Comment: do you think I can change the ETag on the IIS server (no idea whether the web server allows to do that or not)? So when the browser compares the cached ETage to the server one, it will trigger a GET.

Comment: I'm not an ISS guy, but yes, those headers are typically set via the web server configuration.